# jQuery animation trying to fade the white border IN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have a "Hover" animation so a white border appears around a square image when the user brings the mouse arrow over the image.

```
$('#fbid').mouseover(  
                  function( ) 
                  {
                     alert("me");
                     $(this).animate({ "border" : "solid 2px BLACK" }, 1000);
                  }

                  );
```

I do see the alert window that says "me" but the fading transition is not working.

Instead of

```
"border" : "solid 2px BLACK"
```

I tried

```
"border-color" : "WHITE"
```

that did not work either.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colors ***cannot be animated*** with regular jQuery's `animate()` method.

You must use **[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/animate/)** for this.

PS - I would suggest using CSS to do this with `transition` on a `:hover` rule.

### CSS

```
#fbid {
    -webkit-transition: border 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: border 1s ease-in;
    transition: border 1s ease-in;
    border: solid 2px black;
}    
#fbid:hover {
    border-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want the border to look like it expands using animate you could set it to 0 and then change borderWidth using animate like:

```
    $('#fbid').mouseover(function() {
           $(this).css({border: '0px solid BLACK'}).animate({
               borderWidth: 2
           }, 300);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
         $(this).animate({
            borderWidth: 0
        }, 500);
    });
```

Maybe you just want a simple border to appear without expanding...then you should stick to CSS